# I put a blockquote inside a blockquote and I thought I lost my style - Solved

Tags: html, css, nested, quotes

[**Solved**] I now understand that I didn't "lose" my style, it just got applied twice by the nesting. I have now moved my font-size out and restructured my code considerably, and it all works much better now.

[**Original Question**]
In html I am quoting from a book, and the quoted text contains another quote, so I put in a nested blockquote tag. I do get the second level indent okay, but the font style is lost. What is the proper way to do this?

[**EDIT**: code added - I didn't know how to use ctrl-K for quoting html code at first]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>The Two Mouthed Sword</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:100%;
background-color:#d0e4fe;
margin: auto;
max-width: 780px;
}
h2
{
text-align:center;
font-size:1.6em;
}
p
{
font-size:1.3em;
}
blockquote
{
font-size:1.3em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>The Two Mouthed Sword</h2>

<p>When Jesus spoke the parable of the sower...</p>

<blockquote>
14 And in them the prophecy of Isaiah is fulfilled, which says:

<blockquote>
'Hearing you will hear and shall not understand,
</blockquote>

16 But blessed are your eyes for they see, and your ears for they hear;
</blockquote>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not write answers to questions. You should edit a question so that it clearly presents the *problem*, and then perhaps post an answer as an answer. The *question* is still obscure, or even misleading: no style is “lost”. You should have described what you *observed*, in this case that font size is bigger in a nested blockquote.

Comment: I did not understand that that was all I "lost". If I had known, I wouldn't have had the question. I will try to edit the post to make that clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally see it now!

In my blockquote style I have:

font-size:1.3em;

which makes the font bigger, and is being applied twice because of nesting.

Silly me.